# What's the approximate distribution? Replace the true mean with sample mean

Tags: distributions

If say for a random variable $X$, I have observation of $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n$. Let $m$ be the sample mean, and $s$ be the sample standard deviation. Does the new random variable $(X-m)/s$ follow some distribution? It's not $t$-distribution I guess, since for it to be $t$ distributed, $m$ needs to be replaced by true mean.

Can statistics expert shed some light on this?

Comment: What is $x$? Is it an additional independent observation? Why do you think $(x-\text{true mean})/s$ would follow a $t$?

Comment: Do you mean to ask what distribution it would follow *if* something about $x$ was true? (i.e. some null hypothesis).

Comment: If you had the true mean there, why would that be distributed as a $t$?

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are confusing results that hold for a collection of random variables with the case of *one* random variable.

When you have a series of observations, $x_1,...,x_n$, then ***if*** they are *contemporaneous*, ($x_{1t},...,x_{nt}$) they are considered as realizations of *n distinct random variables* (that may be identically and independently distributed, or not). You *cannot*, in this case, assume that all are realizations of the *same* random variable, because a random variable is a real-valued function: this means that at a specific point in time, it can have only one realization (take one value), otherwise it wouldn't be a function but a correspondence: this is why when we have a *cross-sectional* sample of size $n$, we say that "it is comprised of the realization of $n$ random variables", and not  "$n$ realizations of the same random variable".  Note carefully that "same" does not just mean "identically distributed", but ontologically equal.

Assume now that you have a time-series, and the index $1,...,n$ represents different points in time. Can you say that they are all realizations of the *same* random variable? Well in principle you can, but here too, we tend to view a time series as a stochastic process of *distinct* random variables (one for each point in time), that, again, may be identically distributed.

So in general, when looking at a sample, be it cross-sectional or time series, it is advisable to think of it as a collection of realizations of *many* random variables.

Now, when we subtract the mean from a random variable, and divide by the standard deviation, we create the "standardized" version of the variable, that has mean zero and variance (and standard deviation) unity. This is irrespective of the distribution that this variable follows, because, by standard universal properties of these distribution moments
$$Z = \frac {X-\mu}{\sigma} \Rightarrow E(Z) = \frac {1}{\sigma}E(X) - \frac {\mu}{\sigma} = 0$$

and

$$ \text {Var}(Z) = \text {Var}\left(\frac {X-\mu}{\sigma}\right) = \frac {1}{\sigma^2}\text {Var}(X) = \frac {\sigma^2}{\sigma^2} =1$$

The standardized version $Z$ of *one* random variable $X$ follows a distribution that belongs to the same family as the distribution of $X$, with different said parameters - the distribution *family* does not change. So if you don't know the distribution by other means, the distribution of the standardized version will remain unknown.

Now consider the random variable $S_n = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. It is for this and like quantities that the various [Central Limit Theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) talk about and tell that they approach a normal distribution asymptotically.